# How to change array shapes in in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

If I create an array `X = np.random.rand(D, 1)` it has shape `(3,1)`:

```
[[ 0.31215124]
 [ 0.84270715]
 [ 0.41846041]]
```

If I create my own array `A = np.array([0,1,2])` then it has shape `(1,3)` and looks like

```
[0 1 2]
```

How can I force the shape `(3, 1)` on my array `A`?

Comment: Sorry are you looking for `A.reshape([3,1])`?

Answer (score 7):

You can assign a shape tuple directly to [numpy.ndarray.shape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html).

```
A.shape = (3,1)
```

As of 2022, the docs state:

> Setting arr.shape is discouraged and may be deprecated in the future.
> Using ndarray.reshape is the preferred approach.

The current best solution would be

```
A = np.reshape(A, (3,1))
```

Comment: Maybe someone is being picky about your use of 'function'.  `np.reshape` is a function, `A.reshape` a method, and `A.shape=` a functionality?  They all do the same job.

Comment: Setting `shape` will sometimes raise an error, it's not guaranteed to work in all cases. Just adding info, I'm not the down vote.

Comment: The `np.reshape` docs says: `If you want an error to be raise if the data is copied,
    you should assign the new shape to the shape attribute of the array.`  The fact that `a.shape=` does not always work may be a good thing.  Do you have any other cases in mind?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape does not give any warnings about when `.shape=` would be wrong.

Answer (score 6):

```
A=np.array([0,1,2])
A.shape=(3,1)
```

or

```
A=np.array([0,1,2]).reshape((3,1))  #reshape takes the tuple shape as input
```

Answer (score 2):

The numpy module has a `reshape` function and the ndarray has a `reshape` method, either of these should work to create an array with the shape you want:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.reshape([1, 2, 3, 4], (4, 1))
# Now change the shape to (2, 2)
A = A.reshape(2, 2)
```

Numpy will check that the size of the array does not change, ie `prod(old_shape) == prod(new_shape)`. Because of this relation, you're allowed to replace one of the values in shape with `-1` and numpy will figure it out for you:

```
A = A.reshape([1, 2, 3, 4], (-1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the shape directy i.e.

```
A.shape = (3L, 1L)
```

or you can use the resize function:

```
A.resize((3L, 1L))
```

or during creation with reshape

```
A = np.array([0,1,2]).reshape((3L, 1L))
```

Comment: Both assignment to `shape` and `resize` should be avoided unless you know what you're doing because they both have behaviour that will likely surprise new users.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1-D array has the shape (3,):

```
>>>A = np.array([0,1,2]) # create 1-D array
>>>print(A.shape) # print array shape
(3,)
```

If you create an array with shape (1,3), you can use the [numpy.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) mentioned in other answers or [numpy.swapaxes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html):

```
>>>A = np.array([[0,1,2]]) # create 2-D array
>>>print(A.shape) # print array shape
>>>A = np.swapaxes(A,0,1) # swap 0th and 1st axes
>>>A # display array with swapped axes
(1, 3)
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```