# How to convert a (10000, 10, 10) array to (10000, 100, 1) in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am getting IndexError if I try doing it using a for loop.

Any good way to go about it?

Comment: `reshape` should do the job.

Comment: Try `np.reshape()`. This is duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668223/how-to-change-array-shapes-in-in-numpy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`reshape()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) method on the array. (It's also avilable as a NumPy function, `np.reshape()`.)

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random((10000, 10, 10))
arr.reshape((10000, 100, 1))
```

In general, you *almost* never need a loop with NumPy arrays.