# How to convert 4D image array to 3D image array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

image_arr.shape is (501, 128, 128, 1)

My code:

```
n_samples, h, w = images_arr.shape
```

Returns the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

How do I convert above shape to 3D ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change array shapes in in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668223/how-to-change-array-shapes-in-in-numpy)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `(501, 128, 128, 1)` is a 4-tuple - has four values inside. However, `n_samples, h, w` expects three values.

Note now that in the `image_arr.shape` the last value is number of colour channels that you don't need for `n_samples, h, w`.

What you should do then is:

```
n_samples, h, w = image_arr.shape[:3]
```

That is, take first three values (and skip the colour).

Comment: Thank you sir !!

Answer (score 3):

Given that the array shape is `(501, 128, 128, 1)`, the last dimension is not needed, so we can `squeeze` it out, ie. all the relevant data is in the first 3 dimensions in this case:

```
images_arr = np.empty((501, 128, 128, 1))

squeezed = np.squeeze(images_arr)

squeezed.shape
>>> (501, 128, 128)

n_samples, h, w = squeezed.shape
```